# Finding a node in a tree using Depth First Search

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, depth-first-search

I am trying to use Depth First search to find a vertex/node in a tree. I was able to create the DFS algorithm but i don't know how to convert the tree to a code so that i can process it through the algorithm like in the link below
[JavaScript Depth-first search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338974/javascript-depth-first-search)

This was what i was able to do

```
Vertex nodeA = new Vertex();
    Vertex nodeB = new Vertex();
    Vertex nodeC = new Vertex();
    Vertex nodeD = new Vertex();
    Vertex nodeE = new Vertex();
    Vertex nodeF = new Vertex();
    Vertex nodeG = new Vertex();
    Vertex nodeH = new Vertex();

    nodeA.name = "a";
    nodeB.name = "b";
    nodeC.name = "c";
    nodeD.name = "d";
    nodeE.name = "e";
    nodeF.name = "f";
    nodeG.name = "g";
    nodeH.name = "h";

    nodeA.nextNeighbor.add(nodeB);
    nodeA.nextNeighbor.add(nodeC);
    nodeB.nextNeighbor.add(nodeD);
    nodeB.nextNeighbor.add(nodeE);
    nodeB.nextNeighbor.add(nodeF);
    nodeC.nextNeighbor.add(nodeG);
    nodeG.nextNeighbor.add(nodeH);
```

This is the tree structure.

```
    a
   / \
  b   c
 /|\   \
d e f   g
        |
        h
```

This is my code

```
    class Neighbor {
        public int vertexNum;
        public Neighbor next;
        public Neighbor(int vnum, Neighbor nbr) {
                this.vertexNum = vnum;
                next = nbr;
        }
    }

    class Vertex {
        String name;
        Neighbor adjList;
        Vertex(String name, Neighbor neighbors) {
                this.name = name;
                this.adjList = neighbors;
        }
    }
private void dfs(int v, boolean[] visited) {
        visited[v] = true;
        System.out.println("visiting " + adjLists[v].name);
        for (Neighbor nbr=adjLists[v].adjList; nbr != null; nbr=nbr.next) {
            if (!visited[nbr.vertexNum]) {
                System.out.println("\n" + adjLists[v].name + "--" + adjLists[nbr.vertexNum].name);
                dfs(nbr.vertexNum, visited);
            }
        }
    }

public void dfs() {
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[adjLists.length];
        for (int v=0; v < visited.length; v++) {
            if (!visited[v]) {
                System.out.println("\nSTARTING AT " + adjLists[v].name);
                dfs(v, visited);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are basically using a FIFO data structure (array / queue) which will traverse the tree in BFS. You will need to use a LIFO data structure (stack) in order to get the DFS traversal.

Comment: @user1952500 you mean something like what i posted below?

Comment: If you'd like to reply to the other users with new code, [edit] the post, not answer with code your are unsure of (unless it actually does answer the initial  question)

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
public enum State {
     Unvisited, Visited, Visiting;
   } 
// let the start node and the end node be both the nodes.

// Implementation using  DFS.
     public static boolean search(Graph g, Node start, Node end) { 
           LinkedList<Node> stack = new LinkedList<Node>(); // operates as Stack
            for (Node u : g.getNodes()) {
             u.state = State.Unvisited;
            }
            start.state = State.Visiting;
            stack.add(start);
            Node u;
            while(!stack.isEmpty()) 
            {
                  u = stack.removeFirst(); // i.e., pop()
                  if (u != null) {
                    for (Node v : u.getAdjacent()) {
                      if (v.state == State.Unvisited) {
                           if (v == end) {
                                return true;
                            } 
                            else {
                              v.state = State.Visiting;
                              stack.add(v);
                            }
                       }
                    }
               u.state = State.Visited;
                  }
            }
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer the question? If not, edit the question above

Comment: @cricket_007 i just want to know how to create a code out to the tree to use with the algorithm.

Comment: I understand, but you asked a question as an answer to your own question.

Comment: You will need to call dfs on u before visiting the siblings. So basically the subtweets of u is to be processed before looking at the peers of u.